# I can't use a specific port with a docker container

Tags: docker

I don't manage to make the `docker-compose up` work.

When I enter it, I immediately get those errors :

```
Starting test_application_1 ... 
Starting test_application_1 ... error

ERROR: for test_application_1  Cannot start service application: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:5000 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for application  Cannot start service application: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:5000 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

So I used `netstat` (I typed `netstat -av | grep 5000` on the MacOS terminal) to see if the 5000 port was used but the command doesn't display it so I don't think it's actually used...

Here is the content of the `docker-compose.yml` file :

version: "3"
services:
redis:
image: redis
application:
image: some_application
ports:
- 5000:5000

The image `some_application` is from an exercise.

Anyone knows what is happening and how to fix this problem ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article here.

[Port 5000 already in use — MacOS Monterey issue | by Anand Tripathi | Pythonistas | Medium](https://medium.com/pythonistas/port-5000-already-in-use-macos-monterey-issue-d86b02edd36c)

It appears that this is happening with one of the versions of macOS Monterey.

The solution would be to turn off the `AirPlay Receiver` as mentioned in the above article, or use a port other than 5000.

Comment: Thx m8 ! Unfortunately I can't use another port because I need to use the 5000 port for an exercise. I turned off the AirPlay Receiver and it works !  However, I really wonder why this port weren't displayed with netstat !!!

Comment: I tried all, including disabling the airplay one nothing worked. 

In the end, the simple solution worked. 
in app run defined host as 0.0.0.0 and port 5000 explicitly , and bing everything worked 
    app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0",port=5000)
Now run the app as 
    docker run -p 5000:5000 <Image Name>